Chinese with German quotation marks using xeCJK
I would like to place some Chinese words in German text using the xeCJK package. In German, the quotation marks are U+201E and U+201C (or U+201A and U+2018 for single marks).
But the package only defines U+201C and U+201D as part of the FullLeft and FullRight groups which I believe are used to set the glue between Chinese and other glyphs. Anyways, the spacing between the Chinese text and German quotation marks is odd:
\documentclass{report}

\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\RequirePackage{xeCJK} 
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC}

\xeCJKDeclareCharClass{FullLeft}{"201E, "201A}
\xeCJKDeclareCharClass{FullRight}{"201C, "2018}

\begin{document}
    
    Foo ``中文'' Bar 

    Foo ,,中文`` Bar 

\end{document}


I tried to add the above codepoints to the relevant xeCJK classes using \xeCJKDeclareCharClass, but this seems to have no effect.
What is the right approach here? Although I understand the Chinese manual more or less, these settings are a bit opaque to me.

I did some more tests and found that the above gives the right result with Foo „中文“ Bar. Also, when using \xeCJKDeclareCharClass{HalfRight}{"006D} and writing 中文m, the space between the Chinese characters and the letter m is removed as expected. So, my approach seems to be right in a way.
So, somehow the quotation marks (which are TeX ligatures in my examples) are not interpreted as the right Unicode codepoints or the ligature replacement is happening too late ... I don't quite get it.

It seems that the problem has nothing to do with the xeCJK package directly and boils down to:
\documentclass{report}

\newXeTeXintercharclass \gerquotmarksleft
\XeTeXcharclass "201E \gerquotmarksleft
\XeTeXcharclass "201A \gerquotmarksleft

\newXeTeXintercharclass \gerquotmarksright
\XeTeXcharclass "201C \gerquotmarksright
\XeTeXcharclass "2018 \gerquotmarksright

\newXeTeXintercharclass \lettero
\XeTeXcharclass `\o \lettero

\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\XeTeXinterchartoks \lettero \gerquotmarksright = {x}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \gerquotmarksleft \lettero = {x}

\begin{document}

    Foo ,,o`` Bar
    
    Foo „o“ Bar 

\end{document}



I add this as a priliminary answer, but it might not be the best approach as it could also affect other letter combinations. It seems that my problem is similar to this one: The ligatures are formed too late, so that the assignment to the XeTeX character class does not happen as expected.
A solution could be to add a comma (,) and a single grave accent (̀`) to the relevant character class:
\documentclass{report}

\newXeTeXintercharclass \gerquotmarksleft
\XeTeXcharclass "201E \gerquotmarksleft
\XeTeXcharclass "201A \gerquotmarksleft
\XeTeXcharclass `\, \gerquotmarksleft

\newXeTeXintercharclass \gerquotmarksright
\XeTeXcharclass "201C \gerquotmarksright
\XeTeXcharclass "2018 \gerquotmarksright
\XeTeXcharclass `\` \gerquotmarksright

\newXeTeXintercharclass \lettero
\XeTeXcharclass `\o \lettero

\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\XeTeXinterchartoks \lettero \gerquotmarksright = {x}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \gerquotmarksleft \lettero = {x}

\begin{document}

    Foo ,,o`` Bar
    
    Foo „o“ Bar 

\end{document}


The same logic applied to the original problem with Chinese characters (which requires the relevant codepoints to be added to the NormalSpace class as otherwise the font would be changed as well which is not desired here):
\documentclass{report}

\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\RequirePackage{xeCJK} 
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC}

\xeCJKDeclareCharClass{NormalSpace}{"201E, "201A, "002C}
\xeCJKDeclareCharClass{NormalSpace}{"201C, "2018, "0060}

\begin{document}
    
    Foo ``中文'' Bar 

    Foo ,,中文`` Bar 

\end{document}



For the record: With LuaLaTeX and the luatexja-fontspec package, one can do \ltjsetparameter{ alxspmode = {"201E, preonly}, alxspmode = {"201C, postonly} } as it obviously first does the ligatures and only then puts the spaces.
